# view unique values in Combobox using VBA in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

please read my question to end because I test all previous solutions in Stackoverflow and have no answer.
I am trying to display Combobox in the form of an MS Access database using VBA, this Combobox takes its values from one table the problem that I can't display just unique values, Combobox views all values even when I use DISTINCT still view all.
also, I am trying to use GROUP BY but not work.
I know it is a simple problem but how can I solve it?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Exports_imports_Table.ID, Exports_imports_Table.content FROM Exports_imports_Table;
```

Comment: Probably _Exports_imports_Table.ID_ holds unique values - an ID usually does - thus every record will be unique.

Comment: What are you getting? Probably you are using a field that is unique but forces other fields to repeat. Besides, you should post details of clarity. How are your tables? Are you sure there are duplicates?

Comment: @Gustav of corse ID is unique but the value of content is not, I need to display just unique values of content not unique record

Comment: You should be able to figure out the paradox and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ID field is a unique value (and the content field may have duplicates) you cannot include it in a DISTINCT. Try it like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT Exports_imports_Table.content FROM Exports_imports_Table;
```

Does that give you what you expect?

Comment: I can't write this because of the event written Automatically by Access (after you add a combo box you should detect from any table will take its values then the event will be written) even that I tried to wite your code in VBA editor (in event onClick) but it appears in red color and editor reject it

Comment: the same code in your comment. also, I try to write in row source  (place of automatically event witten>> it gives me empty values (maybe because there is no ID in the event)

Comment: I did not give you code, I gave you a SELECT statement. The SELECT statement is a string that you use within your "code".

Answer (score 0):

Don't take the `ID` field in your query builder. Instead of that, select the same field twice, leaving one of them as is, and in another you can give your conditions or formats (if any).

Make sure to change unique values in general properties to "yes".

Save it, and there you are.